# Groovy script to change the svn url in jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, groovy

We have around 200 jobs where svn url has to be updated 
can someone help me with groovy script . we require it through groovy script only

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it have to be a Groovy script? I would simply login to the Jenkins master host and run this `sed` oneliner:

```
$ sed -i 's#svn://old-url#svn://new-url#g' \
         "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/*/config.xml
```

and reload the configuration from disk.